# How to change the format in DateTime?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have this code showing the data in my datagridview but I want to change the format of date and time how do I change the format of DateTime?

```
Datagrid.Columns.Add("datetime",typeof(DateTime));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can specify the format string for that particular column:

```
yourDatagrid.Columns["datetime"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy";
```

**Please note:** I'm not sure about wther `Columns["datetime"]` is correct or not. if it gives error/not accessible means use the column index instead for column name `yourDatagrid.Columns[4].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy";`

Comment: Regarding your note: You can check in the .net documentation that DataGridView.Columns is of type [DataGridViewCOlumnCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumncollection?view=netframework-4.7.2). With that information you could go to the [.net Source of that class](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewColumnCollection.cs,214) and you will notice that the collection can be acccesed by `columnName`.

Answer (score 0):

You can change according to your need by doing this.

```
YourDataGrid.Columns["Column Name"].DefaultCellStyle.Format  = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
```

Comment: I have not underatand what you said. I am newbie here and trying to learn it and trying to answer the question. I know there is so many policies and i will learn it soon.

Comment: Ok, perfect maybe I'm mistaken